# Present one view when notifications are fired in iOS programmatically?

Tags: ios, notifications

I need to present a view when the user enters the app after having received a Local Notification.

I wrote the below code in the `didReceiveLocalNotifications` Method.

```
NotificationModelClass *remainderAlert = [[NotificationModelClass alloc]initWithNibName:@"NotificationModelClass" bundle:nil];

[remainderAlert showRemainderAlert1];
[self.viewController presentModalViewController:remainderAlert animated:YES];
```

It is working fine when the user enter the background through MainView Controller. But I want to present that view in any viewController.

Comment: take a UIView and add it to window.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this for presenting any where in the app:

```
#define AppDelegateObject ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
[AppDelegateObject.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController: remainderAlert animated:YES];
```

If your appdelegate is the receiver of the notification then do it like this:

```
 [self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController: remainderAlert animated:YES];
```